# How can I apply conditional styling to cells in react-table based on user input?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-hooks, frontend, react-table

I am working on a project that requires rendering some csv data in a table format (for which I am using react-table), and doing some user-input verification of values in cells from other columns present in the table.

An example would be: Column 1 -> Cell 1 contains value 1. Column 5 -> Cell 1 has an input field that will provide an equality check to see if the input matches value 1 from Column 1 -> Cell 1.

I am trying to include some conditional styling in column 5 (or honestly styling column 1 would also work) to indicate if the values are matching or not to the user.

This is the code for setting up the columns/data for the table and adding a column for the input field. Right now I am checking the equality of the input using the tableHooks function. The isVerified variable updates correctly and tracks the equality of the input and column value. The issue is that the conditional styling doesn't get applied as the variable gets updated. I am stumped as to why this is broken. Any help is much appreciated!

```
function DataTable() {
const {data} = useContext(CsvContext)

    const _data = useMemo (() => [...data], [data])


    const dataColumns = useMemo(() => _data[0] ? Object.keys(_data[0]).map((key) => {
        return { Header: key, accessor: key}
    }) : [], [_data])

    
    const tableHooks = (hooks) => {
      let isVerified = false
      hooks.visibleColumns.push((columns) => [
        ...columns,
        {
          id: 'Verify',
          Header: 'Verify',
          Cell: ({row}) => (
            <>
            <input onChange={(e) => {
              e.target.value === row.values['ID'] ? isVerified = true: isVerified = false
              console.log(isVerified)
            }}  
            style={{backgroundColor: isVerified ? 'green' : 'white'}} 
            type="text" />
            
            
            </>
          )
        }
      ])
    }

    const tableInstance = useTable({columns: dataColumns, data: _data}, tableHooks, useSortBy)
    const {getTableProps, getTableBodyProps, headerGroups, rows, prepareRow} = tableInstance
```